# Are there any feats that could increase damage output of spellfire's damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, damage, dnd-3e

Using spellfire is a supernatural ability. Are there any feats to increase its damage output? Materials from Dungeon and Dragon magazines are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Only a handful of feats even modify supernatural abilities, and most of those feats won't increase the damage of the supernatural ability spellfire. The feat **Empower Supernatural Ability** (*Tome of Magic* 74) is probably the best candidate, and it's tragically only usable once per day. Further, while that feat's description mentions the possibility of maximizing a supernatural ability, the feat Maximize Supernatural Ability remains apocryphal. Presumably one could talk the DM into allowing something like the feat [Weapon Specialization](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#weapon-specialization) (*Player's Handbook* 102) and picking the supernatural ability spellfire, but this reader doesn't advise a player spend his PC's feats that way.

In other words, if a creature *really* wants to deal more damage with the supernatural ability spellfire, [the creature should increase its Constitution score](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147733/8610) like with the epic feat [Great Constitution](http://dndsrd.net/epicFeats.html#great-constitution) (*Epic Level Handbook* 56).